# strange Latitude and longitude format

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

I'm receiving a strange Latitude Longitude response from my GPS.
The message is the following:

> CGPSINF:0,3948.873779,730.434240,351.238801,20150325115857.283,2,11,0.112258,0.000000"

I know that the latitude is 3948.873779 and the longitude is 730.434240
but how can I convert these to decimal ?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert these to decimal" ? They already look like decimal numbers to me ?

Comment: But how can I use them ? I don't know the units that are represented by the values.

Comment: OK - that's a different question then - you should hit the `edit` link above and make this clearer.

Comment: See also: http://www.edaboard.com/thread298229.html

Comment: Where in there world are you? What are the approximate coordinates?

Comment: Need more details to decode the numbers. Is the location anywhere near to latitude +39 degrees and longitude 7 or 73?

Answer (score 0):

Decimal Degrees = Degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.